# Why is making a class static changing the font and background color?

Tags: java, static, look-and-feel, nimbus

I have 2 classes, a `MainClass` and a `AdminPage`. The `AdminPage` only consists of a `JLabel` with the text `AdminPage`. I use the `Nimbus Look & Feel`.

If I create a new `AdminPage` and put it into the `MainClass` it looks like this:

`AdminPage adminPage = new AdminPage();`

[image: without_static]

But if I change the modifier of the `AdminPage` to `static`, the font becomes bold and the background changes:

`static AdminPage adminPage = new AdminPage();`

[image: with_static]

I really dont understand why this is happening. It's causing me no problems, but a lot of confusion. I suppose this has something to do with how the `UIManager` sets the Look and Feel, but I cant pinpoint the exact cause.

Explanations would be appreciated!

---

Here is my [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)-Code:

**MainClass.java:**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MainClass extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    AdminPage adminPage = new AdminPage();

    public MainClass() {
        setBounds(300, 50, 300, 300);
        setLayout(new MigLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        centerPanel.add(adminPage);
        add(centerPanel, "growx, wrap");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

                    MainClass window = new MainClass();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AdminPage.java:**

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class AdminPage extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("Adminpage");

    public AdminPage() {
        setLayout(new MigLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        contentPanel.add(testLabel);
        add(contentPanel);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to a [comment from Henning Luther](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744055/why-is-making-a-class-static-changing-the-font-and-background-color#comment59164076_35744189) I've tried to initialize the `UIManager` in a static way:

```
static {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

But my class still does not use the intended L&F.

Comment: It's good that you're using EventQueue.invokeLater, to properly execute all of your Swing code in the AWT event dispatch thread.  However, if you make your field static, it is being instantiated outside of the AWT event dispatch thread, and you should expect strange behavior.

Comment: So I should not make the `AdminPage` static at all? Or what other ways do I have to change this behaviour?

Comment: Correct, do not make it static at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the Look&Feel after the AdminPage is instantiated, that's why is not applied to it. The Look&Feel is not changed for all existing UI instances when setting in the UIManager. Since you set AdminPage to static its instantiated on class loading and before main is executed.

Comment: This makes sense! What are the options to handle this situation tough?  Somehow "postpone" the instantiation of the class, so the L&F gets applied? Or don't instantiate the class at all?

Comment: The simpliest would be to set the L&F static also, so its the first thing done. With a static initialiser for example

Comment: I've tried to set the L&F in a static way, but it does not seem to work (see my edit please).

Answer (score 1):

If your AdminPage variable is set to static modifier, the AdminPage constructor will be executed during static initialization phase of your MainClass.

That means it is exected before the main method and especially before this line:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

Thus, other look and feel defaults will apply.